# User can access Sharepoint Online on desktop in office, but not on laptop via wi-fi or on -phone

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-service, access, access-denied, remote

I have a user who can access all areas of SharePoint he has access to using the desktop in the office. However, when trying to access SharePoint on his iphone or on his laptop via wifi he gets the following error message.

> We're sorry but **.**@***.com can't be found in the *****.
>   sharepoint.com directory. Please try again later while we
>   automatically fix this for you.

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

Is it not an issue between organisational (work or school) accounts and personal accounts? I've had multiple users who signed up for Microsoft services with work email addresses before SharePoint Implementation that then have similar issues signing in because they selected the wrong account type. I blame Microsoft for the convoluted design...

Edit: Maybe try signing in with Private Browsing to rule out browser issues.

Comment: he is using his organisational account to sign in on the laptop and iphone. the laptop is a work laptop that he uses for work when offsite.  Signing in with In private browsing returns the same error.

Comment: Is it an on-premise environment or Office 365? If it's on-premise the issue could be that those devices are not on the domain...

Answer (score 0):

Sign into Office portal with your admin work/school account.
Click the Admin tile>Users>Active users.
Check if that user account is in the list.

In the Office 365 admin center click Admin (Admin centers)>SharePoint.
Click user profiles>Manage user profiles>enter the problematic user account>Find.
Check if its user profile can be found.

Access http://YourSharePointSite/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0, and check whether username of the problematic accounts are listed there. if not please add the user and try again .

One more possible reason may be that the user is logged in with an account that doesnt have permission, even if the error shows his work email.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Sign-in-to-Office-or-Office-365-b9582171-fd1f-4284-9846-bdd72bb28426?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US .

If all above still failed , you may using correlation ID and contact Microsoft support .